# Can tokenized payments be tested for chatbot not yet accepted into beta program?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am prototyping a chatbot which will utilize payments.  Facebook's documentation for testing payments seems contradictory:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/complete-guide/payments#test_payments

Section title implies that testing the payment feature only works for 'Buy Button' integrations.  Then at the end of the section is says:

"If you have not been accepted to beta program yet, the test payment feature currently only works for tokenized payments."

I've managed to get the 'Buy Button' integration to work and successfully received the 'payment' callback on the web hook.  But, when I attempt a tokenized payment via a webview I get the following error without any callbacks to the webhook:

"Request Not Completed" popup
"A temporary problem occurred when trying to complete your request.  Please try again later."

Is this expected to work?

Comment: Does this work now if it is a "temporary" issue as it said? I actually encounter the same popup when I was testing "Buy Button". Not sure it is really temporary or just doesn't work at all.

Comment: I'm guessing it is not intended to work, but it would be nice if the team within Facebook could confirm.